# Infinite fraction value in sql query column in c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, decimal, type-conversion

I'm facing a problem which occurs when trying to get the results of this simple sql query in NET (c#):

```
select 1/3 as col from dual
```

`OracleDataReader.GetValue(i)` throws an exception:

> ```
> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.DecimalConv.GetDecimal(IntPtr numCtx)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
> ```

I've discovered that this error occures when number precision goes over 28 digits, so this leads to error:

```
select round(1/3,29) as col from dual
```

but this won't

```
select round(1/3,28) as col from dual
```

Trying to treat column value in c# as Double gets error "Invalid cast"

Does anyone know any approach to avoid this situation except of ubiquitous rounding of number columns?

Comment: Can you tell why you want to do 1/3 in database query !!

Comment: It was just example. You could get infinite fraction as result of some formula - starting from arithmetic mean to more complex calculations

Comment: What happens if you do this: `select 1.0/3.0 from dual`?

Comment: This is obviously a bug in the Oracle library.

Comment: 2 Jeffrey Kemp - the same happens

Answer (score 2):

Since data type is decimal it must be precise. It's not possible to store 1/3 infinite fraction in a decimal type. In general [Conversions from Single or Double to Decimal throw an OverflowException if the result of the conversion is not representable as a Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Thus I need to either read this value as a double or, be sure it's a correct decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You should check below link first, may be you need to add a patch.

http://www.chriscolotti.us/vmware/gotcha-upgrading-vcenter-4-1-to-5-0-with-oracle-11gr2-may-need-client-patch/